# Structure element free function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, structure, free

```
typedef struct //this is a some structure
{
    char *a,*b;
    float x;
}name;
void freeelem(void *x) //the function for element mem free
{
    free(((name*)x)->a);
    free(((name*)x)->b);
}
void* allocelem() // 
{
    void *aux;
    aux=malloc(sizeof(name));
    return aux;
}
int main()
{
    void *x=allocelem();
    ((name*)x)->a="fdasf";
    ((name*)x)->b="fafas";
    freeelem(x);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why this is giving seg fault. Is it the way I acces the structure ?
................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

In the `freeelem` function you call `free` on a pointer which was not obtained by a `malloc`-family function.  This causes undefined behaviour.

To fix this, either remove those `free` calls; or use a `malloc`-family function when assigning to `a` and `b` in `main`.

Also, `malloc(sizeof(Date))` should be `malloc(sizeof(name))`, and yoy should `free(x)` at the end of `main` (or the end of `freeelem`).

Comment: what if i can't use a malloc, if they are 
already allocated somewhere else and i want to free them ? I know the type and the structure.

Comment: @ConstantinMariusManuel the way `free` works is that you can only free things that you malloc'd. There's no other option